# How to connect via LAN Wire and a WIFI Router to the internet (terminal only)

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, cinnamon, lan

I have a big problem. My cinnamon GUI went down. Now I have to reinstall it. Therefore I need an internet connection. Since I can only work within terminal I have to use that to connect to my Wifi. Since I do not have `wpasupplicant` package installed - I am not able to connect to the Wifi. And since I do not have an internet connection - I am not able to download `wpasupplicant`.

Now I have a crossover LAN wire which I put into my Wifi Router (has some LAN slots fortunately). After that I want to be able to connect to the internet via this connection.

I browsed google for a tutorial how to do so but only ended up with tutorials which described the way how to do if you have a GUI available - not the "terminal way".

Therefore I ask you to help me get this up and running and bring my GUI back to live.

*EDIT:*

Command:`ip route`
Output:`none`
Command: `rfkill list`
Output: `lists tpacpi_bluetooth_sw, phy0, hcio0 - all do have "no" at Soft and Hard bocked`
Command: `ifconfig -a` Output: `lists eth0, lo and wlan0 - while only lo is receiving packages`

Comment: Edit your post and add the result of `ip route`, `rfkill list`, `ifconfig -a`, suitably formatted.

Comment: added the informations

Comment: No you didn't. You added a description of what  the person experiencing the problem saw.

Answer (score 0):

For configuring network from a terminal, if you remember (or can use another router to find out) what the network config of your router is (IP range, default GW, DNS servers), you don't even have to configure DHCP, just:

- `ifconfig eth0` *someipinrange* `netmask` *thenetmask*
- `route add default gw` *gateway*
- `ping 8.8.8.8`
- `cp -a /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.backup`
- `echo nameserver` *onenameserverip* `> /etc/resolv.conf`

Except for resolv.conf, these do not actually modify the on-disk configuration, so a reboot will set your machine back to its previous state.